# is it possible to use Jquery Mobile data-transition effect when hide/unhide DIV

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a Jquery Mobile page, with page split. Left side have listview and right side would show detail when clicked on the left side listview. Basically, on click, i am doing hide/unhide of DIV. it is working fine but i want to know if i can use Jquery Mobile data-transition while doing so. Here is the sample code

```
  <div id="left-side">
    <ul data-role="listview"  id="name1" data-theme="d" data-filter="false" data-inset="false" >
    <li data-icon="false" id="K1"><a href="#"   data-transition="slide"> Show A </a></li>
    <li data-icon="false" id="K2"><a href="#"   data-transition="slide"> Show B</a></li>
</ul>
 </div>
 <div id="right-side">
 <div id="A"> Showing DIV A </div>
 <div id="B" style="display:none">Showing DIV B </div>
  </div>


<script>    
 $('li#K1').live('click', function() {
    $("div#A").show();
    $("div#B").hide();
});

 $('li#K2').live('click', function() {
    $("div#A").hide();
    $("div#B").Show();

   });
```

Comment: Not by default, but there are some nice pre-made animations that you get with jQuery such as: `.slideDown()`/`.slideUp()` and `.fadeIn()`/`.fadeOut()`.